# Apply style to one field alone in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/jj7LvmZ73MKUAdecQzpP`
```

Please provide me a solution to apply CSS to one selected field alone and not to whole row in ng-repeat.

I am doing a form validation with mandatory input fields in ng-repeat grid.
I want to check the value of input on blur and display error red border if it is empty. But all fields are highlighted when single field is empty. So I want to highlight fields separately.

The border is disappearing when I click other text box. I want the border to stay till it is filled and not empty. Please guide me. You help is greatly appreciable.

Took the source code from     http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/06/highlight-a-selected-row-in-ng-repeat-using-ng-class/ to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: Please help me in giving solutions or tell the reason for a down vote.

Comment: @one who gave negative please suggest the OP for future reference :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just capture the current context (using '`this`') and set the local variable value ('`selectedRow`') and just use this local variable to set the class in `ng-class`

```
<input type="text" ng-class="{'selected':selectedRow}" ng-blur="setClickedRow($index,this)" name="userName" ng-model="user.name[$index]" ng-required="true"/>

$scope.setClickedRow = function(index,context){
    var val= $scope.user.name[index];
    if(angular.isUndefined(val) || val === null){
    context.selectedRow = true; }
    else{
    context.selectedRow = false; }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MnRwWuujJYxgdIPJsiqy?p=preview)

Ps:- I attached selectedRow with context not with scope of controller :-)